# Pi Zero W Bluetooth Connection Getting Dropped

Tags: bluetooth, pi-zero-w

I have a Rpi Zero W with headless setup and I am trying to connect my bluetooth speaker into my Raspberry Pi W.

I followed this [Setup Bluetooth on Raspberry Pi](https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-bluetooth/)

I followed these steps to be exact

```
1. sudo bluetoothctl
2. pairable on
3. scan on
4. scan off
5. agent on
6. pair xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
7. trust xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
8. connect xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
9. info xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
... will show the success again (some Information are displayed).
10. exit
```

The output is as followed:

When I began to pair, I got the following message, the connected becomes "yes"

```
[bluetooth]# pair FB:58:FA:29:14:20
Attempting to pair with FB:58:FA:29:14:20
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 Connected: yes
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 UUIDs: 00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 UUIDs: 0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 UUIDs: 0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 UUIDs: 0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 ServicesResolved: yes
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 Paired: yes
Pairing successful
```

I noticed that the prompt changed from [bluetooth] to the name of my Bluetooth Speaker [CS BT 20G]. After which I see that the Connected becomes "no"

```
[CS BT 20G]
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 ServicesResolved: no
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 Connected: no
```

I checked the paired-devices

```
[bluetooth]# paired-devices
Device FC:58:FA:29:14:20 MI BT 18I
```

and apply the trust

```
[bluetooth]# trust FB:58:FA:29:14:20
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 Trusted: yes
Changing FB:58:FA:29:14:20 trust succeeded
```

but when I tried to connect, I am getting this

```
[bluetooth]# connect FC:58:FA:29:14:20
Attempting to connect to FB:58:FA:29:14:20
Failed to connect: org.bluez.Error.Failed
```

I ran info and I got these.  Notice that the connected = "no"

```
[bluetooth]# info FC:58:FA:29:14:20
Device FC:58:FA:29:14:20 (public)
        Name: MI BT 18I
        Alias: MI BT 18I
        Class: 0x00260414
        Icon: audio-card
        Paired: yes
        Trusted: yes
        Blocked: no
        Connected: no
        LegacyPairing: no
        UUID: Headset                   (00001108-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Audio Sink                (0000110b-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: A/V Remote Control        (0000110e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
        UUID: Handsfree                 (0000111e-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
[bluetooth]#
```

When I tried to play an mp3 music

```
omxplayer -o alsa example.mp3
```

I am not hearing anything.  Not sure but why my connection is getting dropped by my rpi?

Answer (score 0):

Quite often when pairing has happened but there are issues connecting it is because there is a mismatch between the services offered at both ends of the connection.

With `info` you have shown what services are available on the remote device. If you do `show` then that will let you know what is available on the RPi. I would expect the following to be included on the RPi

```
        UUID: Audio Source              (0000110a-0000-1000-8000-00805f9b34fb)
```

If that looks correct, then I would remove the pairing and try again with a different agent. The fact that you got `no` against `ServicesResolved` suggests their might have been an issue.

```
[CHG] Device FB:58:FA:29:14:20 ServicesResolved: no
```

Instead of using `agent on`, try using `default-agent` to see if that works better.

To get more debug information, there are a couple of other places you can look.

```
service bluetooth status
```

will display error messages from the Bluetooth Daemon at the bottom.

If that doesn't help, then have `sudo btmon -t` running in a separate terminal when you do the pair and connect. It might be hard to read the output of btmon but it could be useful information to add to your question.